# pyspark: new column name for an aggregated field

Tags: pyspark, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code with some aggregation function:

```
new_df = my_df.groupBy('id').agg({"id": "count", "money":"max"})
```

Then the new column I have are `COUNT(id)` and `MAX(money)`. Can I specify the column names myself instead of using the default one? E.g. I want them to be called `my_count_id` and `my_max_money`. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: I've been using `withColumnRenamed` but it's not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use columns not dict:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> my_df.groupBy('id').agg(count("id").alias("some name"), max("money").alias("some other name"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
new_df = my_df.groupBy('id') \
    .agg({"id": "count", "money": "max"}) \
    .withColumnRenamed("COUNT(id)", "my_count_id") \
    .withColumnRenamed("MAX(money)", "my_max_money")
```

or:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

new_df = my_df.groupBy('id') \
    .agg(func.count("id").alias("my_count_id"),
         func.max("money").alias("my_max_money"))
```

Comment: Assuming one aggregate function, say func.sum, is there an efficient way to groupby and alias when there is, say, 1k columns? My current workaround: `X = df.columns[1:]
new_cols = [df.columns[0]] + [x+'_summed' for x in X]
exprs = {x: "sum" for x in X}
dg = df.groupBy("col1").agg(exprs).toDF(*new_cols)`